# Grabbing JSON data with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON URL that I need to grab the variables from and use them as jQuery stings. I've tried several different approaches and all of them are unsuccessful.

**Approach 1**

```
    $.getJSON('http://radio.silvertoneradio.com/rpc/incoleyl/streaminfo.get', function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    });
```

*Resilt*

I receive an 200 OK message, but I do not get any data returned.

**Approach 2**

```
$.ajax({
            url:"http://radio.silvertoneradio.com/rpc/incoleyl/streaminfo.get",
            dataType:'jsonp',
            success:function(data){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                alert(obj.title);
            }
        });
```

*Result*

I receive on 200 OK but the obj value is NULL

**Approach 3**

```
    $.getJSON("http://radio.silvertoneradio.com/rpc/incoleyl/streaminfo.get",function(ajaxresult){
        window.artist = ajaxresult.track.artist;
    });
```

*Resilt*

I receive an 200 OK message, but I do not get any data returned.

Comment: Is this a cross domain request (i.e. `radio.silvertoneradio.com` is not the domain your code is running on)? If so you'll need your target site to implement [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) for this to be possible via AJAX.

Comment: Other solutions may be [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) if they implement it, or otherwise you'll need to proxy the request via your own domain.

Comment: I don't think he would get a 200 OK response if it was a cross domain issue, would he?

Comment: JSONP is implemented, so it should work. Example: http://radio.silvertoneradio.com/rpc/incoleyl/streaminfo.get?callback=foo

Comment: use approach 2,see what happens.Are you using firebug/dev tools to check it is null or not?

Comment: @bsayegh: Yes, `200 OK` is returned but the browser cannot read the response due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Oh, didn't know that (I usually write a local service that would communicate with the other domain so I don't deal with this sort of thing). Appreciate the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't look with attention at the JSON object returned by the service.

What you're looking for is the `data` property of the returned object which is an array.

Something like this do work :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://radio.silvertoneradio.com/rpc/incoleyl/streaminfo.get",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(arguments);
        alert(data.data[0].title);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/floo51/2ZkQq/1/)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you! I'll accept the answer in 5 minutes.